# how to automate many webinars on microsoft teams with the same settings and different invited people

Tags: python, shell, automation, microsoft-teams, webinar

(I have to set 250 webinars on microsoft teams with the same settings and different invited people and these meeting supposed to be daily repeated for two weeks)
example:
let's say that i'm working in a school and this school contain 2000 student we teach all of these students online using microsoft teams webinars all of these students are going to take their lessons on the same time with the same meeting setting but we are going to distribute them into 100 class to create 100 link we need more than one employee but is their any way to automate this task using python

I started learning selenium to solve this problem is it the correct way or should I learn something else because I don't have time to waste

Comment: I have added more details

Comment: There is no API available also to create Webinar in MS Teams.

Comment: is there any some thing in this live can create MS teams meeting links automatically

Comment: There is no other way. To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in [Teams Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).